# Display nested data from observable in Angular 2 view

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, rxjs5

I am using an application state service based on `BehaviorSubject`s in Rx which exposes `Observables` for components to work with. In one of my components I want to show some nested data if its present.

This is what I was trying

```
<div>>{{  sharedState.loadedAccountDetails.accountId | async }}</div>
```

Which yields me an error about not being able to get account Id of undefined which makes sense to me but I thought perhaps the async pipe would help me out here.

In my component shared state is just an `Observable` I don' think there is much to show.

Ultimately, I want to show this data when its present and display nothing when its not there. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `async` pipe directly on the Observable, not values emitted from Observable. In your template use this instead:

```
<div>{{ (sharedState | async)?.loadedAccountDetails.accountId }}</div>
```

With the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    I'm Loaded!
    <div>{{ (sharedState | async)?.loadedAccountDetails.accountId }}</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  sharedState: Observable = null;
  private subject = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.sharedState = this.subject.asObservable();
    setTimeout(_ => {
       this.subject.next({
         loadedAccountDetails: {
           accountId: 42
         }
       });
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

This demo shows number `42` one second after the component has been created.

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fGtNVOZWndYU22U4sRow

Comment: I did have to use `?` on loadedAccountDetails as well to avoid another error but this worked thank you.

Comment: I guess my question is it seems a little ugly  - is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Barry I don't think so if you want to use `async` pipe and keep everything in the template.